# Validate displayName firebase authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently working with Firebase Authentication and absolutely loving it. The only problem right now is that I'm trying to validate the user's display name using my own rules. What I have tried is to use Cloud Firestore to store the display name and other related info such as address, etc. On registration, the user has to declare his/her display name as well as email and password. Somewhere in my code I'm doing this:

```
try {
    await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value);

    await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('/users')
      .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
      .set({
        displayName: displayName.value,
      });
  } catch (err) {
    setIsLoading(false);
    setErrorText(err.message);
  }
```

The problem is that the app also redirects the user when he/she finishes his/her registration to the private area like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (authUser) history.push('/dashboard');
}, [authUser, history]);
```

(`authUser` is stored in Redux and is updated inside `onAuthStateChanged()`) The display name won't be validated because as soon as `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` resolves, `authUser` has a value and immediately redirects the user. It's kind of annoying and would love to know whether there's a better way of organising this bit of code.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Edit:** Firestore rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{documentId} {
        allow read: if request.auth != null
      allow write: if request.auth != null &&
        request.resource.data.displayName is string && 
        request.resource.data.displayName.size() >= 6 && 
        request.resource.data.displayName.size() <= 20
    }
  }
}
```